# how to get a webpage using php curl in xampp

Tags: php, html, curl, xampp

I have recently started working in PHP. In order to get some website content, I am using the following code. But this code always returns "**Empty**". I am using **xampp's PHP** to run this code.

Also, I had already uncommented the expression "**extension=php_curl.dll**" from xampp/php/php.ini file.

Please help me out why it is not returning the webpage content?
Also how to get the specific data from such web pages?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$html=get_data('http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/');
if (!empty($html))
    echo $html;
else
    echo "Empty";

function get_data($location){
    $ch = curl_init($location);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
    }
?>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Is there any errors in apaches error log? Or PHPs?

Comment: the same code is working in my local. so there is something wrong with your CURL settings in xampp. make sure you restarted apache after making any changes.

Comment: @Mahesh, This code works fine with my local page as well. But my problem is how should I use it to get some internet webpage??

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this instead (without or with a custom context):

```
$url = 'http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/';
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo ( $result ) ? $result : 'Empty';
```

http://php.net/file_get_contents

```
$opts = array('http' => 
                array(
                    'method'  => 'GET',
                    'timeout' => 15
                )
        );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Comment: thanx for your help but this code also DIDN'T work,, its showing some errors.

Comment: Right now I am able to view webpages of my LOCAL XAMPP SERVER FILES but for other websites like google.com,, it is showing error "COULD NOT RESOLVE HOST google.com. ERROR NO 6"

Comment: @ash: Are you using protocol prefix in your $url âla "http://" ? Maybe you want to dump the $url to ensure it's correct. Another tip would be to try without DNS and use IP from Google.

Comment: I did the same as you suggested but it didn't work. plz suggest something else, if you have some other trick also.

Comment: I used ip address instead of naming. Also tried with and without prefix "http://". Are you sure whether a local server(like XAMPP) is able to connect with internet to get some webpage's content?